# mathematical notation for the sum of all the elements of the individual diagonals above the secondary diagonal.

Tags: matrices, summation, notation, trace

What is the notation of the sum of the elements above the secondary diagonal for a generic nxn square matrix?

I do not mean the sum of all the elements above the secondary diagonal, but rather the individual sum of all the elements of the "minor" diagonals.

I appreciate your help.